# Unable to Find Proxy Server

Tags: proxy

Running Windows 10 - 64 bit and have installed the newest version of Tor while using TotalVPN to bypass my ISP, which doesn't let Tor go thru.

Tor browser comes up fine, but then I plug in "any" .onion address it gives me a message about "Unable o find the proxy server!"

I have turned off MS Firewall Guest Network as that was showing the TotalVPN connection along with any anti-virus.

Know it's simple config issue, but all the posts relating to Proxy Issues don't mention using a VPN or what is needed to get Tor to look directly thru to the VPN Connection for a safer Tor connection and browsing.

Thanks

Comment: looks similar to https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/when-i-open-tor-and-try-to-use-it-i-get-this-message